# Vulnerabilidades php

Tags: php

Es bueno hacer las consultas a la base de datos dentro del código de php?
Por ejemplo:

```
    <?
$restIds=$_SESSION['restaurants'];
$restIds=substr($restIds,0,strlen($restIds)-1);

$query="SELECT cli.restaurant_id as id, CONCAT(cli.nombre,' ',cli.sucursal) as nombre FROM s3menudt.clientes cli left join options opt on (opt.restId=cli.restaurant_id) WHERE cli.restaurant_id in ($restIds) and opt.controlCatalogos=1";

$result = $mysqli->query($query);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result)!=0)
{
    ?><label>Sucursal:</label>
    <select name="idSucursal" id="idSucursal"><?
    while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
        if($fst==0 and $_SESSION['idSucursal']==''){
            $_SESSION['idSucursal']=$row['id'];
        }
        echo '<option id="'.$row['id'].'" value="'.$row['id'].'"';
        if($row['id']==$_SESSION['idSucursal']) echo ' selected';
        echo '>'.$row['nombre'].'</option>';

        $fst++;
    }
    ?></select><br><?
}
else{ echo "<script>alert('No hay sucursales configuradas para edición Web.'); window.top.location='../landing/index.php'; </script>"; die(); }
?>
</div>
<?
    $col = $col + 2;
    $jsvars .= 'var idSucursal = $("#idSucursal").val();
    ';
    $params .= 'idSucursal';
    $fsucursalCat = false;
}

elseif($fcatalogos){ ?>
<!-- ++++++++++++ CATÁLOGO ++++++++++++ -->
<div class="col-md-2">
<?
```

¿Esto causa vulnerabilidades?

Comment: Intentaba hacer la respuesta larga para que fuera aceptada por stackoverflow es PDO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este código qué presentas tiene una vulnerabilidad importante sobre un ataque de inyección SQL.

**¿Cómo solucionarlo?**

Debes utilizar declaraciones preparadas y consultas "parametrizadas". Estas son declaraciones de SQL que el servidor de la base de datos envía y analiza por separado de cualquier parámetro. De esta manera es imposible para un atacante hacer una inyección de sql.

En tu caso, utilizando MySqli el código se vería algo así:

```
//Creo que tu conexión es $mysqli  ????
$stmt = $dbConnection->prepare('SELECT cli.restaurant_id as id, CONCAT(cli.nombre,' ',cli.sucursal) as nombre FROM s3menudt.clientes cli left join options opt on (opt.restId=cli.restaurant_id) WHERE cli.restaurant_id in ($restIds) and opt.controlCatalogos=1');

$stmt->bind_param('s', $nombre); // 's' especifica el tipo de dato => 'string'

$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    // Hacer cosas seguras :)
}
```

Échale un vistazo a esta pregunta en SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: Tu respuesta aún está incompleta y sigue siendo insegura desde el momento que pasas a la variable dentro del sql, creo que se te pasó el detalle de los marcadores de posición

Comment: @shadow y usando `PDO` para hacer consultas, es seguro?

Comment: @Stn con ambas es seguro, implementado correctamente

Comment: y como se implemente de la manera correcta? yo siempre hago esto: `$sql = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM tabla"); $row = $sql->fetch();` o para insertar hago esto: `$add = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO tabla (valor) VALUES (:valor)"); $add->bindValue(':valor', $_POST['valor']); $add->execute();`

Comment: eso esta bien @Stn por que estas usando también los marcadores de nombre `:nombre` ahora si te vas a mysqli es con `?`

Comment: Entiendo, muchas gracias @shadow